# About sendmmsg msg_len fields with raw IP socket

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, system-calls, raw-sockets

I'm trying to send raw UDP datagrams using a raw IP socket on Linux (I specify both IP and UDP headers).

Should I check the `mmsghdr.msg_len` field after [`sendmmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendmmsg.2.html)? This field designates a number of bytes of a datagram sent, but since I send IP datagrams I think it should always equal to a length of a whole datagram (or not?).

## Notes

I construct a UDP datagram completely by myself. Only one UDP packet (UDP header + data) is encapsulated into an IP datagram.

Comment: Why don't you use just `sendmsg`?

Comment: Because I want to send multiple datagrams at once.